# Flutter: How to display a text from Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have searched a lot but I can't find a solution for this specific problem:
So I want to display a text in my flutter application. But this text shall be variable, so I integrated Firebase to my project. And everything is working well, so I already managed to show images from Firebase but I really don't know how to display a text.

Can you please show me how to do this? Maybe someone could show me the code I need to use to make this work?

This is my code so far, I didn't integrate the specific code to communicate with my Firebase backend, because I don't know how to do this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class MapsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MapsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MapsPageState createState() => _MapsPageState();
}

class _MapsPageState extends State<MapsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Firebase'),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Color(0xffFBD23E), Color(0xffF6BE03)],
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Color(0xffFEFDFD), Color(0xffBDBDB2)],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  text: 'Some text',
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text:
                          'I want this TextSpan to be variable. So if I change the data in my Firestore Database this text shall also change.',
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'And some more text.',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can you please help me? Thank you so much!!

Below is a screenshot of my firestore.

[image: screenshot].

Comment: So get the text and then use `setState(() {});`. If you got images, a text should not be harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
// This below returns the text
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
  DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> document =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('KBADatum/6j5Fnvj0gNkSCRIx7ecH'); // path to doc
  DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> query = await document.get();
  print(query.data());
  return query.data();
}

// and this is how you consume it.
FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
  future: getData(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
      return CircularProgressIndicator();

    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        text: 'Some text',
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: snapshot.data['DatumJahr'], // first text
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: 'And some more text.',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tried it but it shows an invite and never ending CircularProgressIndicator. What exactly do I have to replace ['variable holding text'] with?

Comment: Never ending CircularProgressIndicator? Replace the first CircularProgressIndicator with: Text(‘an error occured’). now if an error occurs, you will know. [‘variable holding text’] should be replaced with the name of the variable you want on firestore.

Comment: I've added a screenshot, so now it's more understandable I hope. I just added the Text('An error occured') and this is what it shows me. As for the variable I've used DatumMonat. Is that right? Because it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should add the screenshot to your question, not my answer. Nevertheless, I have updated my answer (using your document path - KBADatum/6j5Fnvj0gNkSCRIx7ecH - and your first text - DatumJahr). You should be able to use the answer without changing any thing.

Answer (score 1):

The [`snapshots()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html) method provides a stream which you can subscribe to get the latest document changes. To update your ui using the stream, you can use [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) which builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction.

One final thing is that you can't use StreamBuilder as a child to a TextSpan. So, you will either rebuild the `RichText` widget or use [`WidgetSpan`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetSpan-class.html) to rebuild only the span when there is an event on your stream.

Here is an example:

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    text: 'Some text',
    children: [
      // Use WidgetSpan instead of TextSpan, which allows you to have a child widget
      WidgetSpan(
        // Use StreamBuilder to listen on the changes of your Firestore document.
        child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('my_collection')
          .doc('my_document')
          .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final document = snapshot.data; // Get the document snapshot
            final text = document?.data()?['my_text']; // Get the data in the text field 

            return Text(text ?? 'Loading...'); // Show loading if text is null
          },
        ),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'And some more text.',
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Note: I tried to keep the example simple as far as possible, but you can learn more about StreamBuilder to handle errors/data and the state of connection.